# Tool to Decrypt Chrome, Firefox and Edge login information

Tags: passwords, chrome, decryption, firefox

Im new to python but Ive created a couple of programs that can collect the user credentials for Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Microsoft Edge and decrypt them then save the decrypted output to .txt files.

I've bundled them all together with a README.txt file in a .zip file called "CollectAndDecrypt".

You can download it from mediafire here (CollectAndDecrypt.zip):
https://www.mediafire.com/file/4phw12q0ye5qobr/CollectAndDecrypt.zip/file

Comment: This is off-topic. If you want to have a code review use [codereview.se]. If you want to announce some new tool use [/r/netsec](https://www.reddit.com/r/netsec/). This site is for questions only, not for announcements.

Comment: Sorry I didnt realise I put this in the wrong section.

I will post it in netsec? Thanks! :)